# Android "back" button vs Desktop "Escape" key

Tags: javafxports

I am writing an app using JavafxPorts that I am planning on running on both Android and Desktop (PC).

I am trying to keep my code as generic as possible.

My question is... how can I support both the "back" button on Android and have it be equivalent to the "Escape" key on PC?

Basically I want to bring up the menu when the back button is pressed on Android or if the Escape key is pressed on PC.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaFXPorts already has support for the back button on Android: it is mapped to the Escape key.

You can also use Gluon Charm Down, an OSS [project](https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/charm-down) that will let you easily find out about the platform you are running.

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Scene = new Scene(...);

    scene.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, e -> {
        if (KeyCode.ESCAPE.equals(e.getCode())) {
            if (JavaFXPlatform.isAndroid()) {
                // bring up the menu or other Android stuff
            } else {
                // bring up the menu or other Desktop stuff
            }
        });
    }
}
```