# javafxports 8.60.7 - using Back button on Android - none exit application

Tags: android, javafx, javafxports

Using only javafxports 8.60.7 for Android (without Gluon Mobile) - when you press the Back button, the application will not exit.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While JavaFXPorts allows you running plain JavaFX on Android, there are some platform features not implemented by the OpenJFX project, like the back button you mention.

Gluon Mobile deals properly with the back button both in Views and Layers, but if you are not using it, you will have to take care of it.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36302294/android-back-button-vs-desktop-escape-key) already has an answer on how to deal with the Back button on Android.

**Edit**

As for the "exit" part, the Charm Down [OSS](https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/charm-down/pull-requests/) library already provides a service to shutdown the application. It can be easily included on your project by adding the Lifecycle plugin:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.1.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

mainClassName = '<your.main.class>'

jfxmobile {
    downConfig {
        version '3.0.0'
        plugins 'lifecycle'
    }
    android {
        manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
    }
}
```

And now all you need it calling `shutdown` when you want to finish your application via the back button:

```
Services.get(LifecycleService.class).ifPresent(LifecycleService::shutdown);
```

Under the hood, this will check the platform, and call `Platform.exit()` on Desktop or `FXActivity.getInstance().finish()` on Android.

Comment: Yes, my question already has answeras you said, but just add that for Android need to call FXActivity.getInstance().finish();

Comment: To use javafxports is best to use source by José Pereda: https://github.com/jperedadnr/Game2048FX

Comment: Again Thanks José Pereda.

Comment: While the 2048FX project is a valid source, for sure, it was done a while ago, and many of the features described there are now a little bit outdated, and what's more, Gluon Mobile already provides them for you. So my advice will be giving it a try (for free). As for the answer, I'll update it to include the finish call.

Comment: Thanks José. I know already about Gluon Mobile - it is cool framework but for Free license - none support and Indie for 42$/month it's a lot. Gluon is super but support for free license is very horrible. And informations about javafxports is very little.

Comment: Gluon has to do make up for Xamarin.

Comment: The only one from whom I have received support for the use javafxports was you José Pereda. Thanks.