# javafxport's FxActivity.onBackPressed is not called

Tags: android, javafxports

I am using javafxports to launch my gradle based javafx application on android. Using jfxmobile-plugin the application is packed into a single apk file and is working fine. 
In order to override the back pressed behaviour of the FxActivity, I tried to extend this class and add my own Activity class.

```
public class MyActivity extends FxActivity
{
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        System.out.println("onBackPressed");
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

}
```

I added the full quialified name of MyActivity class to the AndroidManifest.xml and again the application works fine except for when I press the android's back button, I can not see the message "onBackPressed" to be printed out. There is another message which shows the back button is pressed and handled by some jfxrt.jar class or something. The message looks like this:

```
my.sample.package.name  I/System.out(16507): KeyEvent: KeyEvent { action=ACTION_UP, keyCode=KEYCODE_BACK, scanCode=0, metaState=0, flags=0x48, repeatCount=0, eventTime=144078131, downTime=144078016, deviceId=-1, source=0x101 } with action = 1
```

Does any one know how to override the onBackPressed in such a way it works?
Another question I have is what javafxports exactly does to close the javafx stage on back pressed?

**EDIT:**

Another question is:

I have two different javafxports android application, name G and B;
These two applications have the same build.gradle files except for the dependencies sections. Application G has a few dependencies like

```
dependencies {
compile 'org.reflections:reflections:0.9.10'
compile 'org.dom4j:dom4j:2.0.0'
compile 'com.jfoenix:jfoenix:1.0.0'
compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:2.1.1'
androidRuntime 'com.gluonhq:charm-android:2.1.1'
}
```

However application B has a lot of dependencies which are mostly my own subprojects; But B do not depend on these two specific artifacts

```
 compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:2.1.1'
 androidRuntime 'com.gluonhq:charm-android:2.1.1'
```

On back pressed, application G exits to android home as expected. However, application B does not react to the back press event on android although a message like the one I mentioned above is printed out on the android's monitor screen.

I want to know why B ignores the back pressed event?

Comment: See this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36302294/android-back-button-vs-desktop-escape-key) and this [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40214212/javafxports-8-60-7-using-back-button-on-android-none-exit-application)

Comment: @JosePereda you are helping me again and again. Hope you can help me on the following too: I've two javafxports android applications. In none of those applications I set any key listener on the scene object. However, one of them does not respond to android's back pressed while the other does. The expected response is to finish the application and come back to android's Home. But this is not the case for the second application. I might be able to catch the back using the way you propose and perform a finish on the FxActivity.getInstance(), however it should be the default behavior I think.

Comment: Instead of starting a new or a followup question on a comment, edit your question or create a new one, and post some come so we can see the difference between both apps.

Comment: I did the same as you guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the Gluon Charm dependencies you are using are quite old. Current version is 4.2.0. I suggest you also update the Gluon IDE plugin to the current 2.5.0 version, as it will generate an up-to-date build.gradle script.

As shown in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36302294/android-back-button-vs-desktop-escape-key), the Android back button is mapped to the ESCAPE key, and Charm implements a key event listener so we can switch Views or close Layers.

Also Charm implements the Charm Down plugin `lifecycle` (see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40214212/javafxports-8-60-7-using-back-button-on-android-none-exit-application)), and when the current View is the Home View, pressing the Android back button has the effect of finishing the activity/application.

Since you are not using Charm dependencies in B, that won't work unless you implement it.

Comment: Thanks. I am not using charm in my own projects. For an android project should I call javafx.Platform.exit along with a call to FxActivity.getInstance().finish()? Or is calling the finish method sufficient?

Comment: You can have a look at the [lifecycle](https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/charm-down/src/tip/plugins/) implementation for Android

Comment: Yes I have already done that. Why there is no Platform.exit for android? Of course activity.finish is going to finish the application from a higher level, I suggest on platform.exit the finishing operation be done automatically. What if someone as a pure javafx programmer call Platform.exit without finishing the activity?

Comment: Platform.exit won't work on Android. That's why we need the `lifecycle::shutdown` call.